# In list.phtml get parentcategory Id or name

Tags: product-attribute

I was wondering how to get the name or Id of a parent category in the list.phtml

I tried

```
$parentname = $product->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getName();
```

I have this

```
$_product->getCategoryIds();
```

Which gets me the category Id of the product but I need to check if the parent category equals a specific category

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: We'd need the rest of your list.phtml and what kind of block but try $_category = Mage::registry('current_category'); I'm unsure what your list.phtml refers to. The assumption would be a category list page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get `current category from product object $product`,you can get current category object using `getCurrentCategory()` function when this is a `category object (Mage_Catalog_Model_Category)`.

you can try this

```
    $category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')
                ->getCurrentCategory();
if($category->getId()){
  $category->getParentCategory()
}
```

OR

```
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
if($category){
  $category->getParentCategory()
}
```

Comment: But what do I get back then the Id or the name or neither of both? So far none of the above work for me
I´ve updated my question a bit